# make a table for

Tags: tdd

math.sqrt(X). the following is the table for it
math.sqrt(X). the following is the table for it

```
     public class SqRoots
{     static final int N = 10;  // How many square roots to compute.

     public static void main ( String [] args )
     {
         // Display a title
         System.out.println( "\n Square Root Table" );
         System.out.println( "-------------------" );

         for ( int i = 1; i <= N; ++i ) // loop 
         {
             // Compute and display square root of i
             System.out.println( "   " + i + ":\t" + Math.sqrt( i ) );
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: It says in increments of `.1`, not `1` So 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc.

Comment: The increments of .1 means 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 etc until you get to 10.

Comment: To make a table you need to use String format: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
public class SqrtTester {
    public static final int MAX_VALUES = 100;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int numValues = ((args.length > 0) ? Integer.valueOf(args[0]) : MAX_VALUES);
        double x = 0.0;
        double dx = 0.1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
            double librarySqrt = Math.sqrt(x);
            double yourSqrt = SqrtTester.sqrt(x);
            System.out.println(String.format("value: %10.4f library sqrt: %10.4f your sqrt: %10.4f diff: %10.4f", x, librarySqrt, yourSqrt, (librarySqrt-yourSqrt)));
            x += dx;
        }
    }

    public static double sqrt(double x) {
        double value = 0.0;
        // put your code to calc square root here
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed the decimal.  I thought the original said 1.0 increments, not 0.1.  You're correct.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple part first: "for every value of x from 0 to 10 in increments of 1" means

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    // do something with x
}
```

The harder part: "build a table"

I would create a class to hold a "row" of data:

```
public class Result {
    private int x;
    private double mathSqrt;
    private double mySqrt;

    public double diff() {
        return mySqrt - mathSqrt;
    }

    // getters and other methods as you need
}
```

Then use the loop over some code to create Result objects for every x value and put it all together.